# How to create encrypted armor file given rsa public key armor

Tags: rust, rust-crypto

I have a string that I need to encrypt to ascii armor with a public key I have as ascii armor.

With gpg, the steps are:

```bash
gpg --import <(echo '
-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
Version: PGP Command Line v10.4.2 (Build 1254) (Linux)

key data here
-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----')

gpg -r identity-of-above@pubkey --armor -e file-of-string-to-encrypt
```

But I need to do this in a program without depending on gpg. It feel like the [pgp crate](https://docs.rs/pgp/latest/pgp/index.html) and / or [rsa crate](https://docs.rs/rsa/latest/rsa/index.html) should be what I seek, but I cannot even figure out how to load the key from a string.

How does one load the key then generate an encrypted file using rust? This is what I have written so far:

```rust
use indoc::indoc;
use rsa::{pkcs1::DecodeRsaPublicKey, PaddingScheme, PublicKey, RsaPublicKey};

fn main() {
    let pem = indoc! {"
        -----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
        Version: PGP Command Line v10.4.2 (Build 1254) (Linux)

        key data here
        -----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
    "};
    let pub_key = RsaPublicKey::from_pkcs1_pem(&pem).unwrap();
    let data = b"contents I want to encrypt";
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
    let enc_data = pub_key
        .encrypt(&mut rng, PaddingScheme::new_pkcs1v15_encrypt(), &data[..])
        .expect("failed to encrypt");
}
```

But I get this compile error:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Asn1(Error { kind: Pem(HeaderDisallowed), position: None })', src/main.rs:51:54
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

Fair enough, but I can't find how to do the same key loading procedure for my key type. How do I load this key?

Answer (score 2):

With the help of some folks on the Rust Discord server, I did manage to get this sorted. It requires the use of [Message](https://docs.rs/pgp/latest/pgp/composed/message/enum.Message.html), [SignedPublicKey](https://docs.rs/pgp/latest/pgp/composed/signed_key/public/struct.SignedPublicKey.html), and the [Deserializable trait](https://docs.rs/pgp/latest/pgp/composed/trait.Deserializable.html). It ends up looking like this.

```rust
use indoc::indoc;
use pgp::composed::message::Message;
use pgp::composed::signed_key::public::SignedPublicKey;
use pgp::composed::Deserializable;
use pgp::crypto::sym::SymmetricKeyAlgorithm;
use std::fs::File;

fn main() {
    let pem = indoc! {"
        -----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
        Version: PGP Command Line v10.4.2 (Build 1254) (Linux)

        key data here
        -----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
    "};
    let pub_key = SignedPublicKey::from_string(&pem).unwrap().0;
    assert!(pub_key.verify().is_ok());
    let data = "contents I want to encrypt";
    let fname = "encdata";
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
    let mut file = File::create(fname).unwrap();
    let msg = Message::new_literal(&fname, &data)
        .encrypt_to_keys(&mut rng, SymmetricKeyAlgorithm::AES128, &[&pub_key])
        .unwrap()
        .to_armored_writer(&mut file, None);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

faced the same problem, and fix it by delete the tab in front of each line between indoc! " and "}

```
    fn main() {
        ...
        let pem = indoc! {"
        -----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
        Version: PGP Command Line v10.4.2 (Build 1254) (Linux)

        key data here
        -----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
        "};
        ...
    }
```